# Given p, how do I use the Fitch system to prove $\neg \neg p$?

Tags: logic

Given p, how do I use the Fitch system to prove $ \neg \neg p $?

I thought it should be as simple as assuming the negative, introducing a contradiction and eliminating the negation to end up with $\neg \neg p$, but I can't even get to step 3 with [the Stanford Fitch system](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/exercises/exercise_04_09.html):

1) $p$ ---------------------premise
2) | $\neg p$ -----------------assumption
3) | $p \implies \neg p$ -------implication introduction 1,2
4) $\neg \neg p$ -----------------negation elimination 3

Obviously I am not quite getting it with the Fitch system, so any explanation would be greatly appreciated. It does seem trivially obvious that $p \Leftrightarrow \neg \neg p$ but I am having trouble expressing this with Fitch:

1) $p$ ---------------------premise
2) | $\neg p$ -----------------assumption
3) | $p$ -------------------reiteration 1
4) $\neg p \implies p$ ---------implication introduction 2,3

...from here tho, I can't figure out how to get $p \implies \neg p$ which I assume would which along with 4 I think would give me what I need to get $\neg \neg p$ from the negation elimination.

Comment: The Nat Deduction proof is: assume $p$ and assume $\lnot p$. Derive a contradiction (usually symbolized with $\bot$) and then apply "negation" introduction to derive $\lnot \lnot p$, discharging assumption $\lnot p$. Conclude with $\to$-intro. Details can depend on the implementation...

Comment: In "usual" implementation of [Nat Ded](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) the negation-intro rule is: from $\Gamma, \varphi \vdash \bot$, derive: $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \varphi$.

Comment: Other forms can be : from $\Gamma, \varphi \vdash \psi$ and $\Gamma, \varphi \vdash \lnot \psi$, derive $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \varphi$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA how would I squeeze that into Fitch?

Comment: If the rule you are allowed to use is the second one, the proof must be *(i)* $p, \lnot p \vdash p$, *(ii)* $p, \lnot p \vdash \lnot p$ and then apply the rule to conclude with: $p \vdash \lnot \lnot p$.

Comment: The "Fitch" tool implements Natural Deduction; thus, you have to review the basic inference rules. Different implememtations may differ on some details, basically only in the management of $\lnot$ and $\bot$ (the contradiction): some has both; some only $\bot$ (and $\lnot P$ is defined as $P \to \bot$); some only $\lnot$, and in this last case you have to explicitly derive a couple of contradictory formulas in order to use $\lnot$-intro.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I only wish the Stanford course were as smart as you are with logic... :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're so close!  Here's how to proceed:

1) $p$ ---------------------premise
2) | $\neg p$ -----------------assumption
3) | $p$ -------------------reiteration 1
4) $\neg p \implies p$ ---------implication introduction 2-3
5) | $\neg p$ -----------------assumption
6) | $\neg p$ -------------------reiteration 5
7) $\neg p \implies \neg p$ -------implication introduction 5-6
8) $\neg \neg p$ ----------------negation introduction  4,7

Comment: Thanks - I'm glad to see I was at least on the right track. Color me obtuse, but steps 5 and 6 just seem ...very counter-intuitive. Any resources you could recommend on getting proficient with the Fitch System? The Stanford online course gives a very cursory explanation prior to throwing a bunch of problems at the student and I am having trouble getting a feel for it.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy Yeah, formal proofs can certainly be that way: you'd think it would be all logical ... and yet sometimes you have to do these weird moves to make it fir the formal 'straightjacket' of formal logic.  Unfortunately, there is really just only 1 way to get good at these: do lots of them, and build up your 'repertoire' of strategies and common proof patterns.

Comment: thanks, I'm nowhere near anyone that uses formal logic, so I appreciate your comments. The Stanford course is fine for being free and all, but a little frustrating for lack of instruction... Also the discussion forum there has not been a great resource, but hey, I wanted to get to know Fitch - thank goodness for stack exchange!

Comment: Interesting... reworking the proof with the Stanford tool it seems step 6 is redundant as it allows implication introduction with just the assumption of 5... But the essential point seems to be that where phi implies psi and not psi, a negation of phi can be introduced...? Neither this nor sub-proof/super-proof relationships are very clearly explained in the course...

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy Yes, the first step of a subproof can be regarded as the last step of a subproof as well, so Reiteration would indeed be unnecessary. It does help readability though I think.

Comment: @Bram28 The rule you used for 8 is RAA not negation introduction, and it's non-intuitionistic, and $p \vdash \neg \neg p$ can be done in intuitionistic logic.

Comment: @KennyLau Another example!

Comment: @Bram28 which book is it now?

Comment: @KennyLau An online course: http://intrologic.stanford.edu/lessons/lessons.html

Comment: @Bram28 Found it in the fifth slide of [section 4.4](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/sections/section_04_04.html), where it is called negation introduction and is intuitionistic. (it's another formulation of neg intro, and it is not RAA.)

Comment: @Bram28 sorry, you're right all along. disregard what I said. (and this isn't an unfortunate naming)

Comment: @KennyLau Oh, ok ... like I said, I am not versed in intuitionistic logic ..

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
(1) & \quad P & \text{Assumption} \\
(2) & \quad \quad \lnot P & \text{Assumption} \\
(3) & \quad \lnot \lnot P & \text{Contradiction of } 1,2 \\
(4) & P \implies \lnot \lnot P & \implies-\text{Intro}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Is 3 a contradiction of 1,2? It is a contradiction of 2, certainly, but I'm not following how you derive this, nor how you would derive $\neg \neg p$ from 1-4. Can you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy 3 is obtained by a proof by contradiction kind of rule just as in my proof above: since the assumption of $\neg P$ 2 leads to a contradiction with the $P$ in 1, we can reject the assumption of $\neg P$, and thus obtain $\neg \neg P$ in 3, and thus by conditional introduction obtain 4 from the subproof 1-3.  But: this proof uses rules that are different from the Stanford rules. They're valid rules, but not how they are formally defined in *your* formal proof system.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy 3 is obtained from the rule $\dfrac{ a \vdash \{b, \lnot b\} } {\lnot a}$ , it just happens in this case $a = b = p$, and $b$ and $a$ are the same reference.